# Optaplanner ConstraintVerifier

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am using constraintverifier to verify constraints, but the first constraint always returns 0, and the other constraints are OK.

```
@Test
public void requiredNumberOfBucketsTest() {
    Trolley trolley = new Trolley();
    trolley.setBucketCapacity(1000);
    trolley.setBucketNum(1);
    trolley.setTrolleyId(IdWorker.getIdStr());

    TrolleyStep trolleyStep = new TrolleyStep();
    trolleyStep.setId(IdWorker.getIdStr());
    trolleyStep.setProductVolume(20000000);
    trolleyStep.setOrderNumber("order-0");
    verifier.verifyThat(OrderPickingConstraintProvider::requiredNumberOfBuckets)
            .given(trolleyStep).penalizesBy(1);
}
```

No matter how my constraint is written, I always get 0 score
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTyVZ.png)

```
 public Constraint requiredNumberOfBuckets(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(TrolleyStep.class)
            .penalizeLong(" Required number of buckets ",
                    HardSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT,
                    trolleyStep -> 10);
 }
```

Comment: The assertion error shown in the image tells the constraint is "distance to previous", which is not the constraint you shared. Are you sure you run the right test?

Comment: It is the same constraint. I forgot to modify the description. The problem has been solved. When I give a plan variable to the plan entity, I get the correct result, even if the plan variable does not participate in the current constraint

Comment: That makes sense - `forEach(...)` only gives you entities where variables are not `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Lukas, all entities with any null planning variable are not selected with `forEach()`. This works naturally even with over-constrained planning (nullable=true). But if there are multiple planning variables on the entity, as in your case, I understand this might not feel that natural. Unfortunately, we can't detect which (subset of) planning variable(s) your constraint is written to, so we can't smart filter the entities on `forEach()`.

**Solutions**:

A) Rewrite your constraint to include null vars by using `forEachIncludingNullVars()` instead of `forEach()`:

```
 public Constraint requiredNumberOfBuckets(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(TrolleyStep.class)
            ...;
 }
```

B) Alternatively, don't use **nullable=true** variables and initialize all planning variables in your unit tests.